# iptables, nat and server in lan

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding

I have several ip addresses, X.Y.Z.A - X.Y.Z.D, in one interface (eth1)

X.Y.Z.A is my gateway, with NAT. This works.

I want to access one computer in my LAN (eth0) (Q.W.E.R) from outside, from the X.Y.Z.B ip.

I tried the following rules:

```
iptables -t NAT -A PREROUTING -d X.Y.Z.B -j DNAT --to-destination Q.W.E.R
iptables -t NAT -A POSTROUTING -s Q.W.E.R -j SNAT --to-source X.Y.Z.B
```

with no success. Opening a browser and typing X.Y.Z.B still shows my firewalls web server, and RDP times out.

Can anybody tell me, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exclude Q.W.E.R from the previous NAT rule
i.e. your general nat rule should be AFTER those two above (or put them with -I )

Comment: You mean

iptables -t NAT -A PREROUTING -d X.Y.Z.B -j DNAT --to-destination Q.W.E.R
iptables -t NAT -A POSTROUTING -s Q.W.E.R -j SNAT --to-source X.Y.Z.B
iptables -t nat -A postrouting -o $wan_iface -j SNAT --to $WAN_IP

?

still not good...

Comment: sorry, it works, just not from the lan.